# shell-escape error with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shell-escape

I am using TeXMaker under Linux Mint and try to compile a document containing a pgfplot within a figure. I cannot manage to run the shell-escape command properly. From the `.log` I am able to see, that the `shell-escape` command is executed, but it somehow fails afterwards (see the log file, errors at the end). After this error, "dimension too large" causes `pdflatex` to stop.
I added the following commands to the preamble:

```
 \tikzexternalize[shell escape=-shell-escape]
 \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
```

And compiled with:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
```

The figure I would like to compile is:

```
 \begin{figure}
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ,width=0.8\linewidth
            ,title={Phasenverschiebung $\phi (f)$}
            ,axis x line*=bottom
                ,axis y line*=left
            ,tick label style={font=\small}
            ,grid=both
            ,tick align=outside
                ,tickpos=left
            ,xlabel={Frequenz [Hz]}
            ,ylabel={Phasenverschiebung [$\pi$]}
            ,xmin=1
            ,xmax=2
            ,ymin=-1
            ,ymax=1 
    ]
    \addplot+[
                ,raw gnuplot
                ,myblue
                ,mark=o
                %,smooth
                ,only marks
                ]
                gnuplot {
                plot './CONTENT/Test.dat' using 1:2;
                };
            \addlegendentry{$\phi$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Phasenverschiebung in Abhängigkeit der Frequenz}
\label{fig:A}
\end{figure}
```

See the log below:

```
(./CONTENT/arne_plot1.tex
\openout3 = `Sem_Main-figure0.md5'.

\openout3 = `Sem_Main.auxlock'.


===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape  -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Sem_Main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Sem_Main}\input{Sem_Main}"' 
========runsystem(pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Sem_Main-figure0"\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Sem_Main}\input{Sem_Main}")...executed.

\openout3 = `Sem_Main.auxlock'.


! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Sem_Main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Sem_Main}\input{Sem_Main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'Sem_Main-figure0' (expected one of pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'Sem_Main-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.53    \end{tikzpicture}

This error message was generated by an \errmessage command, so I can't   give any explicit help.Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by order and method.
\openout3 = `Sem_Main.pgf-plot.gnuplot'.

 runsystem(gnuplot Sem_Main.pgf-plot.gnuplot)...executed.

PGFPlots: reading {Sem_Main.pgf-plot.table}
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgf@xx 

l.53    \end{tikzpicture}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

! Dimension too large.
    <recently read> \pgf@xx

(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
52329 strings out of 493027
1206027 string characters out of 6134075
3858645 words of memory out of 5000000
54978 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
20482 words of font info for 101 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1145 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
67i,13n,103p,10396b,2074s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I am able to compile the document without the `shell-escape`.
As always: Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**:

```
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsubscript on input line 3906.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip46
\belowcaptionskip=\skip47
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box26
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./SYSTEM/options.tex

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 KOMAoptions{ % read documentation for KOMAScript providing the documentc...

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1642 strings out of 493027
27998 string characters out of 6134075
144751 words of memory out of 5000000
5248 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
3940 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
42i,1n,46p,294b,47s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Even though it says "`\begin{document}`" missing, it compiles fine without the plot, so I am assuming the error is not in `options.tex`, but withinn the plot itself? I also found the error in the main `.log`:

```
 l.53   \end{tikzpicture}

 Runaway definition?
 ->\pgfsyssoftpath@movetotoken {123.11621pt} {22.84926pt}\pgfsyssoftpath@curvetos
 upportatoken \ETC.
 ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
 <argument> ...tpath@curvetosupportbtoken {123.1162
                                                      1pt}{21.74467pt}\pgfsyssof...
 l.53   \end{tikzpicture}

 !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
 Transcript written on Sem_Main.log.
```

Comment: The error message as such can be found in `Sem_Main-figure0.log` (according to the error message). I suppose it is "Dimension too large" as well. In this case, the data file contains numbers which are _way_ bigger than the limit. Does it work if you omit `xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax`?

Comment: I omitted xmin, xmax,ymin, ymax and compiled again, unfortunately it still doesn't work. The Sem_Main-figure0.log is now added to my post.

Comment: Sounds as if your data file results in too many samples and pgfplots ran out of memory. Please search for "tex capacity exceeded" on this site in order to resolve the issue. I would expect this to happen with or without image externalization.

Comment: Did the trick of Christian solve your problem or do you need further assistance?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem... There is still something wrong with the externalization...

Comment: Ok, unfortunately it is a bit hard to help you, because we don't have the `Test.dat`. Could you add (at least a small part of) it to your question so that the error still persists? This will be very helpful for us.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, you can find the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwwh528vkk5kwli/Test.dat?dl=0

Comment: As you can see from [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341368/95441) everything works fine (as expected). Could you have a look of your versions of TikZ and PGFPlots, please. Are they perhaps outdated and updating to the most recent versions does help?

Answer (score 1):

*(Not really an answer but this way I can show that it is working and it incorporates the `Test.dat` data.)*

---

Sorry, but everything works as expected without an error using the below code with the mentioned versions of the packages etc.

```
% used TikZ v3.0.1a and PGFPlots v1.14 from MiKTeX 2.9
% works using pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
%
\begin{filecontents}{Test.dat}
0.  1.
0.0010000000000000009   0.8959156785243744
0.0020000000000000018   0.8959156785243744
0.0030000000000000027   0.6851119894598156
0.0040000000000000036   0.632411067193676
0.0050000000000000044   0.5270092226613966
0.006000000000000005    0.4216073781291173
0.007000000000000006    0.158102766798419
0.008000000000000007    -0.05270092226613966
0.009000000000000008    -0.316205533596838
0.010000000000000009    -0.4216073781291173
0.01100000000000001 -0.6851119894598156
0.01200000000000001 -0.7378129117259553
0.013000000000000012    -0.790513833992095
0.014000000000000012    -0.8432147562582346
0.015000000000000013    -0.8959156785243744
0.016000000000000014    -0.8959156785243744
0.017000000000000015    -0.8959156785243744
0.018000000000000016    -0.8432147562582346
0.019000000000000017    -0.7378129117259553
0.020000000000000018    -0.7378129117259553
0.02100000000000002 -0.6851119894598156
0.02200000000000002 -0.6851119894598156
0.02300000000000002 -0.5270092226613966
0.02400000000000002 -0.47430830039525695
0.025000000000000022    -0.36890645586297766
0.026000000000000023    -0.316205533596838
0.027000000000000024    -0.2635046113306983
0.028000000000000025    -0.2635046113306983
0.029000000000000026    -0.10540184453227933
0.030000000000000027    -0.05270092226613966
0.031000000000000028    0.
0.03200000000000003 0.158102766798419
0.03300000000000003 0.21080368906455865
0.03400000000000003 0.21080368906455865
0.03500000000000003 0.316205533596838
0.03600000000000003 0.36890645586297766
0.03700000000000003 0.4216073781291173
0.038000000000000034    0.47430830039525695
0.039000000000000035    0.5797101449275363
0.040000000000000036    0.632411067193676
0.041000000000000036    0.7378129117259553
0.04200000000000004 0.790513833992095
0.04300000000000004 0.8432147562582346
0.04400000000000004 0.8432147562582346
0.04500000000000004 0.8432147562582346
0.04600000000000004 0.8432147562582346
0.04700000000000004 0.790513833992095
0.04800000000000004 0.7378129117259553
0.04899999999999993 0.6851119894598156
0.04999999999999993 0.632411067193676
0.050999999999999934    0.4216073781291173
0.051999999999999935    0.36890645586297766
0.052999999999999936    0.158102766798419
0.05399999999999994 0.
0.05499999999999994 -0.2635046113306983
0.05599999999999994 -0.36890645586297766
0.05699999999999994 -0.47430830039525695
0.05799999999999994 -0.5270092226613966
0.05899999999999994 -0.6851119894598156
0.05999999999999994 -0.7378129117259553
0.06099999999999994 -0.790513833992095
0.061999999999999944    -0.790513833992095
0.06299999999999994 -0.7378129117259553
0.06399999999999995 -0.7378129117259553
0.06499999999999995 -0.7378129117259553
0.06599999999999995 -0.7378129117259553
0.06699999999999995 -0.632411067193676
0.06799999999999995 -0.5270092226613966
0.06899999999999995 -0.47430830039525695
0.06999999999999995 -0.47430830039525695
0.07099999999999995 -0.36890645586297766
0.07199999999999995 -0.316205533596838
0.07299999999999995 -0.2635046113306983
0.07399999999999995 -0.2635046113306983
0.07499999999999996 -0.10540184453227933
0.07599999999999996 -0.05270092226613966
0.07699999999999996 0.
0.07799999999999996 0.10540184453227933
0.07899999999999996 0.158102766798419
0.07999999999999996 0.158102766798419
0.08099999999999996 0.2635046113306983
0.08199999999999996 0.36890645586297766
0.08299999999999996 0.4216073781291173
0.08399999999999996 0.4216073781291173
0.08499999999999996 0.5797101449275363
0.08599999999999997 0.5797101449275363
0.08699999999999997 0.632411067193676
0.08799999999999997 0.632411067193676
0.08899999999999997 0.6851119894598156
0.08999999999999997 0.7378129117259553
0.09099999999999997 0.7378129117259553
0.09199999999999997 0.7378129117259553
0.09299999999999997 0.7378129117259553
0.09399999999999997 0.6851119894598156
0.09499999999999997 0.632411067193676
0.09599999999999997 0.5797101449275363
0.09699999999999998 0.36890645586297766
0.09799999999999998 0.316205533596838
0.09899999999999998 0.158102766798419
0.09999999999999998 -0.05270092226613966
0.10099999999999998 -0.10540184453227933
0.10199999999999998 -0.21080368906455865
0.10299999999999998 -0.4216073781291173
0.10399999999999998 -0.47430830039525695
0.10499999999999998 -0.5797101449275363
0.10599999999999998 -0.5797101449275363
0.10699999999999998 -0.6851119894598156
0.10799999999999998 -0.6851119894598156
0.10899999999999999 -0.6851119894598156
0.10999999999999999 -0.6851119894598156
0.11099999999999999 -0.6851119894598156
0.11199999999999999 -0.632411067193676
0.11299999999999999 -0.5270092226613966
0.11399999999999999 -0.5270092226613966
0.11499999999999999 -0.47430830039525695
0.11599999999999999 -0.47430830039525695
0.11699999999999999 -0.36890645586297766
0.118   -0.316205533596838
0.119   -0.21080368906455865
0.12    -0.158102766798419
0.121   -0.10540184453227933
0.122   -0.05270092226613966
0.123   -0.05270092226613966
0.124   0.
0.125   0.158102766798419
0.126   0.158102766798419
0.127   0.2635046113306983
0.128   0.316205533596838
0.129   0.36890645586297766
0.13    0.4216073781291173
0.131   0.4216073781291173
0.132   0.47430830039525695
0.133   0.5797101449275363
0.134   0.5797101449275363
0.135   0.632411067193676
0.136   0.632411067193676
0.137   0.632411067193676
0.138   0.632411067193676
0.139   0.632411067193676
0.14    0.632411067193676
0.14100000000000001 0.5797101449275363
0.14200000000000002 0.47430830039525695
0.14300000000000002 0.36890645586297766
0.14400000000000002 0.316205533596838
0.14500000000000002 0.21080368906455865
0.14600000000000002 0.158102766798419
0.14700000000000002 -0.05270092226613966
0.14800000000000002 -0.158102766798419
0.14900000000000002 -0.316205533596838
0.15000000000000002 -0.4216073781291173
0.15100000000000002 -0.47430830039525695
0.15200000000000002 -0.5270092226613966
0.15300000000000002 -0.5270092226613966
0.15400000000000003 -0.632411067193676
0.15500000000000003 -0.5797101449275363
0.15600000000000003 -0.5797101449275363
0.15700000000000003 -0.5797101449275363
0.15800000000000003 -0.5270092226613966
0.15900000000000003 -0.5270092226613966
0.16000000000000003 -0.5270092226613966
0.16100000000000003 -0.4216073781291173
0.16200000000000003 -0.4216073781291173
0.16300000000000003 -0.36890645586297766
0.16400000000000003 -0.316205533596838
0.16500000000000004 -0.21080368906455865
0.16600000000000004 -0.158102766798419
0.16700000000000004 -0.10540184453227933
0.16800000000000004 -0.10540184453227933
0.16900000000000004 -0.05270092226613966
0.17000000000000004 0.
0.17100000000000004 0.158102766798419
0.17200000000000004 0.158102766798419
0.17300000000000004 0.21080368906455865
0.17399999999999993 0.2635046113306983
0.17499999999999993 0.36890645586297766
0.17599999999999993 0.36890645586297766
0.17699999999999994 0.4216073781291173
0.17799999999999994 0.47430830039525695
0.17899999999999994 0.47430830039525695
0.17999999999999994 0.5270092226613966
0.18099999999999994 0.5797101449275363
0.18199999999999994 0.632411067193676
0.18299999999999994 0.5797101449275363
0.18399999999999994 0.5797101449275363
0.18499999999999994 0.632411067193676
0.18599999999999994 0.5270092226613966
0.18699999999999994 0.47430830039525695
0.18799999999999994 0.4216073781291173
0.18899999999999995 0.36890645586297766
0.18999999999999995 0.316205533596838
0.19099999999999995 0.21080368906455865
0.19199999999999995 0.158102766798419
0.19299999999999995 -0.05270092226613966
0.19399999999999995 -0.10540184453227933
0.19499999999999995 -0.2635046113306983
0.19599999999999995 -0.316205533596838
0.19699999999999995 -0.4216073781291173
0.19799999999999995 -0.47430830039525695
0.19899999999999995 -0.47430830039525695
0.19999999999999996 -0.5270092226613966
0.20099999999999996 -0.5270092226613966
0.20199999999999996 -0.5270092226613966
0.20299999999999996 -0.5270092226613966
0.20399999999999996 -0.5270092226613966
0.20499999999999996 -0.47430830039525695
0.20599999999999996 -0.47430830039525695
0.20699999999999996 -0.4216073781291173
0.20799999999999996 -0.4216073781291173
0.20899999999999996 -0.316205533596838
0.20999999999999996 -0.2635046113306983
0.21099999999999997 -0.2635046113306983
0.21199999999999997 -0.21080368906455865
0.21299999999999997 -0.10540184453227933
0.21399999999999997 -0.10540184453227933
0.21499999999999997 -0.05270092226613966
0.21599999999999997 0.
0.21699999999999997 0.10540184453227933
0.21799999999999997 0.158102766798419
0.21899999999999997 0.21080368906455865
0.21999999999999997 0.21080368906455865
0.22099999999999997 0.2635046113306983
0.22199999999999998 0.316205533596838
0.22299999999999998 0.36890645586297766
0.22399999999999998 0.4216073781291173
0.22499999999999998 0.4216073781291173
0.22599999999999998 0.4216073781291173
0.22699999999999998 0.47430830039525695
0.22799999999999998 0.5270092226613966
0.22899999999999998 0.5270092226613966
0.22999999999999998 0.5270092226613966
0.23099999999999998 0.47430830039525695
0.23199999999999998 0.47430830039525695
0.23299999999999998 0.47430830039525695
0.23399999999999999 0.4216073781291173
0.235   0.36890645586297766
0.236   0.316205533596838
0.237   0.158102766798419
0.238   0.10540184453227933
0.239   -0.05270092226613966
0.24    -0.10540184453227933
0.241   -0.158102766798419
0.242   -0.2635046113306983
0.243   -0.316205533596838
0.244   -0.36890645586297766
0.245   -0.47430830039525695
0.246   -0.47430830039525695
0.247   -0.47430830039525695
0.248   -0.47430830039525695
0.249   -0.47430830039525695
0.25    -0.47430830039525695
0.251   -0.4216073781291173
0.252   -0.4216073781291173
0.253   -0.36890645586297766
0.254   -0.316205533596838
0.255   -0.316205533596838
0.256   -0.2635046113306983
0.257   -0.21080368906455865
0.258   -0.158102766798419
0.259   -0.10540184453227933
0.26    -0.10540184453227933
0.261   -0.05270092226613966
0.262   0.
0.263   0.
0.264   0.10540184453227933
0.265   0.158102766798419
0.266   0.21080368906455865
0.267   0.2635046113306983
0.268   0.316205533596838
0.269   0.316205533596838
0.27    0.36890645586297766
0.271   0.36890645586297766
0.272   0.4216073781291173
0.273   0.4216073781291173
0.274   0.47430830039525695
0.275   0.47430830039525695
0.276   0.47430830039525695
0.277   0.47430830039525695
0.278   0.47430830039525695
0.279   0.4216073781291173
0.28    0.36890645586297766
0.281   0.36890645586297766
0.28200000000000003 0.2635046113306983
0.28300000000000003 0.158102766798419
0.28400000000000003 0.10540184453227933
0.28500000000000003 0.
0.28600000000000003 -0.05270092226613966
0.28700000000000003 -0.10540184453227933
0.28800000000000003 -0.21080368906455865
0.28900000000000003 -0.316205533596838
0.29000000000000004 -0.316205533596838
0.29100000000000004 -0.36890645586297766
0.29200000000000004 -0.4216073781291173
0.29300000000000004 -0.47430830039525695
0.29400000000000004 -0.47430830039525695
0.29500000000000004 -0.4216073781291173
0.29600000000000004 -0.4216073781291173
0.29700000000000004 -0.4216073781291173
0.29800000000000004 -0.4216073781291173
0.29899999999999993 -0.36890645586297766
0.29999999999999993 -0.316205533596838
0.30099999999999993 -0.316205533596838
0.30199999999999994 -0.2635046113306983
0.30299999999999994 -0.2635046113306983
0.30399999999999994 -0.158102766798419
0.30499999999999994 -0.158102766798419
0.30599999999999994 -0.10540184453227933
0.30699999999999994 -0.05270092226613966
0.30799999999999994 0.
0.30899999999999994 0.
0.30999999999999994 0.158102766798419
0.31099999999999994 0.158102766798419
0.31199999999999994 0.21080368906455865
0.31299999999999994 0.21080368906455865
0.31399999999999995 0.21080368906455865
0.31499999999999995 0.2635046113306983
0.31599999999999995 0.36890645586297766
0.31699999999999995 0.36890645586297766
0.31799999999999995 0.4216073781291173
0.31899999999999995 0.36890645586297766
0.31999999999999995 0.4216073781291173
0.32099999999999995 0.4216073781291173
0.32199999999999995 0.4216073781291173
0.32299999999999995 0.4216073781291173
0.32399999999999995 0.4216073781291173
0.32499999999999996 0.36890645586297766
0.32599999999999996 0.36890645586297766
0.32699999999999996 0.316205533596838
0.32799999999999996 0.2635046113306983
0.32899999999999996 0.158102766798419
0.32999999999999996 0.158102766798419
0.33099999999999996 0.
0.33199999999999996 -0.05270092226613966
0.33299999999999996 -0.10540184453227933
0.33399999999999996 -0.158102766798419
0.33499999999999996 -0.21080368906455865
0.33599999999999997 -0.2635046113306983
0.33699999999999997 -0.316205533596838
0.33799999999999997 -0.36890645586297766
0.33899999999999997 -0.36890645586297766
0.33999999999999997 -0.36890645586297766
0.34099999999999997 -0.4216073781291173
0.34199999999999997 -0.4216073781291173
0.34299999999999997 -0.36890645586297766
0.344   -0.316205533596838
0.345   -0.36890645586297766
0.346   -0.316205533596838
0.347   -0.316205533596838
0.348   -0.2635046113306983
0.349   -0.21080368906455865
0.35    -0.21080368906455865
0.351   -0.10540184453227933
0.352   -0.10540184453227933
0.353   -0.05270092226613966
0.354   -0.05270092226613966
0.355   0.158102766798419
0.356   0.10540184453227933
0.357   0.158102766798419
0.358   0.158102766798419
0.359   0.21080368906455865
0.36    0.21080368906455865
0.361   0.2635046113306983
0.362   0.316205533596838
0.363   0.36890645586297766
0.364   0.36890645586297766
0.365   0.36890645586297766
0.366   0.4216073781291173
0.367   0.36890645586297766
0.368   0.4216073781291173
0.369   0.36890645586297766
0.37    0.36890645586297766
0.371   0.36890645586297766
0.372   0.36890645586297766
0.373   0.2635046113306983
0.374   0.21080368906455865
0.375   0.158102766798419
0.376   0.158102766798419
0.377   0.
0.378   -0.05270092226613966
0.379   -0.10540184453227933
0.38    -0.10540184453227933
0.381   -0.21080368906455865
0.382   -0.2635046113306983
0.383   -0.316205533596838
0.384   -0.316205533596838
0.385   -0.316205533596838
0.386   -0.36890645586297766
0.387   -0.36890645586297766
0.388   -0.316205533596838
0.389   -0.316205533596838
0.39    -0.36890645586297766
0.391   -0.316205533596838
0.392   -0.2635046113306983
0.393   -0.316205533596838
0.394   -0.2635046113306983
0.395   -0.2635046113306983
0.396   -0.158102766798419
0.397   -0.10540184453227933
0.398   -0.05270092226613966
0.399   -0.05270092226613966
0.4 -0.05270092226613966
0.401   -0.05270092226613966
0.402   0.
0.403   0.158102766798419
0.404   0.158102766798419
0.405   0.21080368906455865
0.406   0.21080368906455865
0.40700000000000003 0.2635046113306983
0.40800000000000003 0.21080368906455865
0.40900000000000003 0.2635046113306983
0.41000000000000003 0.316205533596838
0.41100000000000003 0.36890645586297766
0.41200000000000003 0.36890645586297766
0.41300000000000003 0.36890645586297766
0.41400000000000003 0.36890645586297766
0.41500000000000004 0.36890645586297766
0.41600000000000004 0.36890645586297766
0.41700000000000004 0.316205533596838
0.41800000000000004 0.36890645586297766
0.41900000000000004 0.2635046113306983
0.42000000000000004 0.21080368906455865
0.42100000000000004 0.158102766798419
0.42200000000000004 0.158102766798419
0.42300000000000004 0.10540184453227933
0.42399999999999993 0.
0.42499999999999993 -0.10540184453227933
0.42599999999999993 -0.10540184453227933
0.42699999999999994 -0.21080368906455865
0.42799999999999994 -0.21080368906455865
0.42899999999999994 -0.2635046113306983
0.42999999999999994 -0.2635046113306983
0.43099999999999994 -0.2635046113306983
0.43199999999999994 -0.316205533596838
0.43299999999999994 -0.316205533596838
0.43399999999999994 -0.316205533596838
0.43499999999999994 -0.36890645586297766
0.43599999999999994 -0.316205533596838
0.43699999999999994 -0.316205533596838
0.43799999999999994 -0.2635046113306983
0.43899999999999995 -0.316205533596838
0.43999999999999995 -0.21080368906455865
0.44099999999999995 -0.158102766798419
0.44199999999999995 -0.158102766798419
0.44299999999999995 -0.10540184453227933
0.44399999999999995 -0.10540184453227933
0.44499999999999995 -0.05270092226613966
0.44599999999999995 -0.05270092226613966
0.44699999999999995 0.
0.44799999999999995 0.
0.44899999999999995 0.158102766798419
0.44999999999999996 0.158102766798419
0.45099999999999996 0.21080368906455865
0.45199999999999996 0.21080368906455865
0.45299999999999996 0.21080368906455865
0.45399999999999996 0.21080368906455865
0.45499999999999996 0.316205533596838
0.45599999999999996 0.316205533596838
0.45699999999999996 0.2635046113306983
0.45799999999999996 0.36890645586297766
0.45899999999999996 0.36890645586297766
0.45999999999999996 0.36890645586297766
0.46099999999999997 0.316205533596838
0.46199999999999997 0.36890645586297766
0.46299999999999997 0.316205533596838
0.46399999999999997 0.2635046113306983
0.46499999999999997 0.21080368906455865
0.46599999999999997 0.21080368906455865
0.46699999999999997 0.158102766798419
0.46799999999999997 0.158102766798419
0.469   0.158102766798419
0.47    0.
0.471   -0.05270092226613966
0.472   -0.10540184453227933
0.473   -0.158102766798419
0.474   -0.21080368906455865
0.475   -0.21080368906455865
0.476   -0.21080368906455865
0.477   -0.316205533596838
0.478   -0.2635046113306983
0.479   -0.316205533596838
0.48    -0.316205533596838
0.481   -0.316205533596838
0.482   -0.316205533596838
0.483   -0.2635046113306983
0.484   -0.2635046113306983
0.485   -0.2635046113306983
0.486   -0.21080368906455865
0.487   -0.158102766798419
0.488   -0.158102766798419
0.489   -0.10540184453227933
0.49    -0.10540184453227933
0.491   -0.10540184453227933
0.492   -0.05270092226613966
0.493   0.
0.494   0.10540184453227933
0.495   0.158102766798419
0.496   0.158102766798419
0.497   0.158102766798419
0.498   0.21080368906455865
0.499   0.21080368906455865
0.5 0.21080368906455865
0.501   0.2635046113306983
0.502   0.2635046113306983
0.503   0.2635046113306983
0.504   0.316205533596838
0.505   0.316205533596838
0.506   0.36890645586297766
0.507   0.2635046113306983
0.508   0.2635046113306983
0.509   0.21080368906455865
0.51    0.2635046113306983
0.511   0.2635046113306983
0.512   0.21080368906455865
0.513   0.158102766798419
0.514   0.158102766798419
0.515   0.10540184453227933
0.516   0.
0.517   -0.05270092226613966
0.518   -0.10540184453227933
0.5189999999999999  -0.10540184453227933
0.52    -0.10540184453227933
0.5209999999999999  -0.21080368906455865
0.522   -0.21080368906455865
0.5229999999999999  -0.2635046113306983
0.524   -0.2635046113306983
0.5249999999999999  -0.2635046113306983
0.526   -0.2635046113306983
0.5269999999999999  -0.2635046113306983
0.528   -0.2635046113306983
0.5289999999999999  -0.2635046113306983
0.53    -0.21080368906455865
0.5309999999999999  -0.2635046113306983
0.532   -0.21080368906455865
0.5329999999999999  -0.21080368906455865
0.534   -0.158102766798419
0.5349999999999999  -0.10540184453227933
0.536   -0.10540184453227933
0.5369999999999999  -0.05270092226613966
0.538   -0.05270092226613966
0.5389999999999999  0.
0.54    0.
0.5409999999999999  0.10540184453227933
0.542   0.10540184453227933
0.5429999999999999  0.158102766798419
0.544   0.21080368906455865
0.5449999999999999  0.21080368906455865
0.546   0.21080368906455865
0.5469999999999999  0.21080368906455865
0.548   0.21080368906455865
0.5489999999999999  0.2635046113306983
0.55    0.2635046113306983
0.5509999999999999  0.2635046113306983
0.552   0.2635046113306983
0.5529999999999999  0.21080368906455865
0.554   0.2635046113306983
0.5549999999999999  0.21080368906455865
0.556   0.21080368906455865
0.5569999999999999  0.21080368906455865
0.558   0.21080368906455865
0.5589999999999999  0.21080368906455865
0.56    0.158102766798419
0.5609999999999999  0.10540184453227933
0.562   0.
0.563   0.
0.5640000000000001  -0.05270092226613966
0.565   -0.10540184453227933
0.5660000000000001  -0.10540184453227933
0.567   -0.158102766798419
0.5680000000000001  -0.21080368906455865
0.569   -0.21080368906455865
0.5700000000000001  -0.21080368906455865
0.571   -0.2635046113306983
0.5720000000000001  -0.2635046113306983
0.573   -0.2635046113306983
0.5740000000000001  -0.2635046113306983
0.575   -0.21080368906455865
0.5760000000000001  -0.2635046113306983
0.577   -0.2635046113306983
0.5780000000000001  -0.21080368906455865
0.579   -0.158102766798419
0.58    -0.10540184453227933
0.581   -0.10540184453227933
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
    \tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
%            % commented these because at least the x range is given outside
%            % of the data provided in `Test.dat'
%            xmin=1,
%            xmax=2,
%            ymin=-1,
%            ymax=1,
            only marks,
        ]
        \addplot+[
            raw gnuplot,
            mark=o,
        ] gnuplot {
            plot 'Test.dat' using 1:2;
        };
            \addlegendentry{$\phi$}

        % you don't need to use `raw gnuplot' when you just want to plot
        % some table data without any manipulation
        % (that PGFPlots cannot do itself)
        \addplot+ [
            mark=o,
            mark size=1pt,
        ] table [
            x index=0,
            y index=1,
        ] {Test.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Can you provide some information on which platform you use and which program, e.g. TexMaker ....?

Comment: As I have stated in the first two comment lines of my code I used MiKTeX, so I am under Windows. And I don't think that there is a relation to the editor (which in my case is [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/)).